# How to best maintain status in a parent-child relationship

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, relational-database

I couldn't figure out how to word the title of this question to make it clear, so here's my best shot at an explanation:

My client has a series of tables which are in parent-child relationships with each other. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.First_Level (
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    active BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1),
    CONSTRAINT PK_First_Level PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Second_Level (
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    first_level_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    active BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Second_Level PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SecondLevel_FirstLevel FOREIGN KEY (first_level_id) REFERENCES dbo.First_Level (id)
)


CREATE TABLE dbo.Third_Level (
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    second_level_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    active BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(1),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Third_Level PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ThirdLevel_SecondLevel FOREIGN KEY (second_level_id) REFERENCES dbo.Second_Level (id)
)
```

The tricky part is that if a parent is marked as no longer being active (active = 0) then any children under it should also be considered as no longer active. However, a child **can** be marked as no longer active even if the parent is still active.

I'm looking for suggestions on how best to enforce these business rules. I could overlay views which would then look at all parents to determine the final active flag for any given row, but my client already has a great deal of code written around these tables.

I could enforce the rules through triggers, but I'm hoping that there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Triggers aren't elegant?

Comment: @canon: Inelegant ones aren't. :)

Comment: Do you need to know what was marked inactive for institutional memory?  For example if someone marks a 3rd level entry inactive, then marks its parent inactive and changes it back to active, do you need to know that the 3rd level entry should still be inactive?

Comment: @HABO: That's an excellent question. My understanding (I've only been with this client for just over a week) is that they would not need that information, but I'll check on that.

Comment: @canon: IME, no - most of the time they are not. Even well-written triggers tend to hide business logic and hurt maintainability. Poorly written ones can of course kill performance and even well-written ones are likely to hurt it. I'll generally use triggers for auditing purposes (even this is going away with CDC), setting update_date values, etc. but I try not to do any more than that in triggers.

Comment: i think triggers are the way to go here.

Comment: @user1535855 Although you are not sure that Views would be the best way, I think the code to update the tables would be much more than the one required by Views, that's why I proposed a solution which used them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't like to put business rules in the database, but the development is divided about this. Anyway, here's a solution that applies the rule you described from a logical level, i.e. without changing the underlying tables. This allows you to limit the updates and ensure that the active/inactive state of each row, in all tables, is not coupled too tightly with the others.

```
SELECT
    FL.id AS FirstLevelId
    ,FL.active AS FirstLevelActive
    ,SL.id AS SecondLevelId
    -- If First Level is Active, ignore it by passing it as NULL to coalesce, and take the value of Second_Level.active
    -- If First Level is not active, take its value as the "active" value for this level. 
    ,COALESCE(NULLIF(FL.active, 1), SL.active) AS SecondLevelActive
    ,TL.id AS ThirdLevelId
    -- Same as above, but with one more level involved
    ,COALESCE(NULLIF(FL.active, 1), NULLIF(SL.active, 1), TL.active) AS ThirdLevelActive
FROM
    First_Level FL
    LEFT JOIN
    Second_Level SL ON
        (SL.first_level_id = FL.id)
    LEFT JOIN
    Third_Level TL ON
        (TL.second_level_id = SL.id)
```

**Advantages**
 - The Active status is retrieved by applying the business rules, but leaving intact the data of the levels.
 - No updates needed, therefore no need to track cascaded updates, nor to use triggers.
 - By putting this query in a View, the application will always get the correct status "on the fly"

**Drawbacks**
 - Solution is rigid, due to the table structures
 - Adding a new lawyer would require altering the query accordingly

*Acknowledgements*
Thanks to Ghidorah, composer of Toilet Story 4, for the inspiring music.

Comment: Unless this is a stored procedure, you're not putting "business rules" in the database. You're making a query from your client, which filters it to what the client wants to see.

Answer (score 1):

The set of currently active top level entries is a RESTRICT view on the entire set top-level of top-level entries :

CREATE VIEW FIRST_LEVEL_ACTIVE AS SELECT * FROM FIRST_LEVEL WHERE ACTIVE ... ;

The set of currently active second-level entries are those that satisfy the condition that the entries are themselves still active, and their parent appears in the view just defined :

CREATE VIEW SECOND_LEVEL_ACTIVE AS (SELECT * FROM SECOND_LEVEL WHERE ACTIVE ...) NATURAL JOIN FIRST_LEVEL_ACTIVE;  /* or whatever other operation that achieves the same effect as NATURAL JOIN */

The set of currently active third-level entries are those that satisfy the condition that the entries are themselves still active, and their parent appears in SECOND_LEVEL_ACTIVE

etc. etc.

For dealing with UPDATEs to these views, the SQL standard has INSTEAD OF triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You could enforce the business rules by having the update statement also update the children when you update the active status:

```
-- Delete first level
DECLARE @FirstLevelIdToDelete INT
SET @FirstLevelIdToDelete = x

UPDATE  Third_Level
SET     Third_level.active = 0
FROM    Third_Level tl
JOIN    Second_Level sl ON tl.second_level_id = sl.id
WHERE   sl.first_level_id = @FirstLevelIdToDelete

UPDATE  Second_Level
SET     active = 0
WHERE   Second_Level.first_level_id = @FirstLevelIdToDelete

UPDATE  First_Level
SET     active = 0
WHERE   id = @FirstLevelIdToDelete

-- Delete second level
DECLARE @SecondLevelIdToDelete INT
SET @SecondLevelIdToDelete = x

UPDATE  Third_Level
SET     active = 0
WHERE   Third_Level.second_level_id = @SecondLevelIdToDelete

UPDATE  Second_Level
SET     active = 0
WHERE   id = @SecondLevelIdToDelete

-- Delete third level
DECLARE @ThirdLevelIdToDelete INT
SET @ThirdLevelIdToDelete = x

UPDATE  Third_Level
SET     active = 0
WHERE   id = @ThirdLevelIdToDelete
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe that the front-end uses stored procedures for all access to the DB, so this could work there. The same requirement isn't placed on ETL processes, etc. though, so it would likely still let some bad data get through. Still, for lack of a better solution this might be the best that I can do right now. Your currently in first place for suggested solutions ;)

Comment: therefore triggers.. i think you should reconsider those.

Comment: I don't know if you can run into this situation, but if a user wants to "undo" a "de-activation" of some level, how will you know which children must then automatically be "un-de-activated" along with their parent, and which ones must be left as is because they already were de-activated ?  Invent an extra value to distinguish between "de-activated by user" and "de-activateed by trigger" ?